# Find an unknown vector in a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let's assume that $a$ is an $n\times1$ vector and $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $n\times n$ (not necessarily hermitian) matrix how can I find unknown vector $a$ in equation
${a^HA_1a}={a^HA_2a}$ ?

Comment: It's a quadratic equation equivalent to $a^H(A_1-A_2)a=0$; this at least reduces the problem to one matrix.

Comment: could you please explain more

Comment: The problem is the same as finding solutions to $a^HAa=0$, where $A=A_1-A_2$. Now try your hand with a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ to see what happens.

Comment: it's a problem with two unkown and one equation

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: you mean this problem has infinite solutions?

Comment: It can have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: if we have a constraint like $f(a)>1$ can we find just one solution?and how?

Comment: ($$f:R^n--->R$$)